# Длительная обработка данных в Django

Tags: django

Пишу проект на Django, клиент через браузер отправляет данные на сервер, где они должны обработаться всякими сложными алгоритмами. Процесс обработки данных очень длительный(2-3 часа). В ходе обработки клиент должен видеть текущий прогресс. Вопросы:

- Запускать код обработки данных прямо
         во view, является ли нормальным
         решением?
- Или лучше реализовать обработку в отдельном питон приложении, что-то типа вычислительного сервера, который будет иметь api, по которому можно отправить данные на обработку, и проверить текущий статус?
- Или есть
         какой-то более правильный путь для
         такой задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. точно нет
2. посмотрите [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)